# Generic selection using jquery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate

As a relative jquery novice please bear with me if there is a simple solution to my problem. Using jquery validate works beautifully when selecting by `unique ID` eg.

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    debug: false,
    rules:
    {
         field1: "Required"
    },
    messages:
    {
         field1: "Required"
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
         $.post('formAction.php', $("#myForm").serialize(), function(data) {
            $('#results').html(data);
         });
    }
});
```

I need to extend this to work generically with a number of automatically generated forms `myForm1, myForm2` etc.

Can I validate via a common class selector `$("myForm")` and then apply the `submitHander` to the specific form (`myForm1`, `myForm2`, etc.) eg:

```
$(".myForm").validate({
    debug: false,
    rules:
    {
         field1: "Required"
    },
    messages:
    {
         field2: "Required"
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
         $.post('formAction.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
            $('#results').html(data);
         });
    }
});
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('[id^=myForm]').validate(); // work for id pattern myForm1, myForm2...
                              // this selector will target forms whose id start
                              // with myForm
```

or

```
$('.myForm').validate() // giving a common class to all forms
```

---

Autocomplete calling `submitHandler` like this

```
 validator.settings.submitHandler.call( validator, validator.currentForm );
```

Which means `this` will refer to the `validator object` not the `form`, so use the `form` argument to refer to the form and serialize it's fields like this

```
 $(form).serialize()
```

So, within you submit handler instead of `$(this).serialize()` use, `$(form).serialize()`.

Comment: Thanks, I should have been more verbose. I've tried both a generic call selector $('.myForm') and using wildcards $('[id^=myForm]'). This is fine but how then do I reference the individual form selected. In the example above I've illustated this with $(this) mbut that selector is not valid. Hope I've better explained?

Answer (score 0):

e validate method does not chain references to the form so as suggested $(form).serialize still refers to the 1st form sharing the common class. Huge help though as it put me on the right track to find the work around:-

https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/157

```
$(".myForm").each(function(index,element) {
  $(element).validate({

    debug: false,

    rules:
    {
         field1: "Required"
    },
    messages:
    {
         field2: "Required"
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
         $.post('formAction.php', $(form).serialize(), function(data) {
            $('#results').html(data);
         });
    }
  });
 });
```